# Python: How to set n previous rows as True if row x is True in a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My df (using pandas):

```
Value    Class
1        False
5        False
7        False
2        False
4        False
3        True
2        False
```

If a row has Class as True, I want to set all n previous rows as true as well. Let's say n = 3, then the desired output is:

```
Value    Class
1        False
5        False
7        True
2        True
4        True
3        True
2        False
```

I've looked up similar questions but they seem to focus on adding new columns. I would like to avoid that and just change the values of the existing one. My knowledge is pretty limited so I don't know how to tackle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is replace `False` to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then use back filling function with `limit` parameter by [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html), last replace missing values to `False` and convert values to boolean:

```
n = 3
df['Class'] = df['Class'].where(df['Class']).bfill(limit=n).fillna(0).astype(bool)
print (df)
   Value  Class
0      1  False
1      5  False
2      7   True
3      2   True
4      4   True
5      3   True
6      2  False
```